# Wrapping template template parameter class with SWIG

Tags: c++, templates, swig, template-templates

I have a C++ class like the following:

```
template< template<typename> class ContainerType, typename MemberType>
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass(ContainerType<MemberType>* volData);
}
```

which I am trying to wrap with SWIG. My MyClass.i looks like:

```
%module MyClass
%{
  #include "SimpleContainer.h"
  #include "MyClass.h"
%}

%include "SimpleContainer.h"
%include "MyClass.h"

%template(MyClass_SimpleContainer_Int) MyClass<SimpleContainer, int>;
```

However, SWIG seems to have problems with the template template parameter. When compiling it complains with the error message:

```
MyClassPYTHON_wrap.cxx:30545:3: error: ‘ContainerType’ was not declared in this scope
```

Looking at that line in the generated code, it contains the line:

```
ContainerType< int > *arg1 = (ContainerType< int > *) 0 ;
```

For some reason it's using verbatim the dummy template name as the name of the class, even though I've told it that this instantiation of the class should have a ContainterType of SimpleContainer.

Is there any way that I can get around this bug? I found mention of it in the [SWIG tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=101645&aid=1861407&group_id=1645) but I couldn't understand the workaround mentioned in the last post and also that bug is 4 years old.

I'm using SWIG 1.3.40 and GCC 4.5.1 on openSUSE 11.4

Comment: I've upgraded to SWIG 2.0.3 and the bug is still present.

Answer (score -1):

The first line of your C++ header looks strange to me. Try the following:

```
template<class ContainerType, typename MemberType>
```