# Wrapping a c++ template template template class using swig

Tags: python, c++, templates, swig

I have a class structure which uses a lot of templates which I want to swig. 
I know there are several similar questions around on stack overflow ([Wrapping template template parameter class with SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215165/wrapping-template-template-parameter-class-with-swig), [wrapping specialised c++ template class with swig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757642/wrapping-specialised-c-template-class-with-swig,..).) but none of them worked for my case.

A minimal example looks like the following

**insane_template.h**

```
#pragma once

class CustomAttrs{
public:
    enum dattr1d{pos,vel,someCustomCaseVar, d1dLast};
};


template <class T> 
class A
{
public:
    T attributes;
};


template <template<class> class A, class T> 
class B : public A<T>
{

};


template<template<template<class> class, class> class Op, template<class> class X, class T>
class C : public Op<X,T>
{
};

template class A<CustomAttrs>;
template class B<A, CustomAttrs>;
template class C<B, A, CustomAttrs>;
```

My **insane_template.i** is fairly simple:

```
%module insane

%{
#include "./insane_template.h"
%}

%include "./insane_template.h"

%template(AC) A<CustomAttrs>;
%template(BAC) B<A, CustomAttrs>;
%template(CBAC) C<B, A, CustomAttrs>;
```

When I try to swig it via `swig -v -c++ -python -outdir ./ nsane_template.i` I get the error `Error: Syntax error in input(1).`

If I comment out the class `C` it works as expected. Unfortunately it is one of the most neccessary classes which needs to be wrapped.

So my question: Is (and if how) it possible to swig a template construct like `template<template<template<class> class, class> class Op, template<class> class X, class T>`

Am I right that the parser is not able to parse such template constructs?

It would be fine for me only to swig the `class C<B, A, CustomAttrs>`

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE**
I am using swig 3.0.5 on ubuntu 14.04 with gcc/g++ 4.8.4

Comment: It's very possible this is not supported by SWIG, especially since it's an unclosed bug reported in the link you've provided.

Comment: yes I thought so, even the reported bug wasn't a problem for me when using swig 3.0.5.

Comment: What you can do is to instantiate your templates and create a proper binary interface - in this way you don't need to wrap templates. Another benefit is that you can create release and debug versions which are binary compatible.